# [hardware-combination]: lock it away

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[hardware-combination](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware-combination) decorates questions about anything that contains two or more non-identical components.

- mixing RAM of different speeds
- how to orient the fan on a computer case that contains a combination of hardware
- adding a hard disk to a computer
- using two different video cards at the same time
- converting one type of output to another
- where to find a particular device driver
- etc.

Totally Meta, and it applies to most questions that aren't about software, so it doesn't really differentiate anything.  I was going to suggest nuking it from orbit, but there were a bunch of questions with that as the only tag.

I started going through it, figuring I would clean up those, and questions where it was pure decoration, and then ask here about any questions that were actually about combining hardware, where the tag might refer to something meaningful.  No such luck.

The collection is now down to 30 questions.  I didn't want to wipe out the tag without checking here.

Comment: ha - that's a pretty good title employing double entendre! Yes, meta and garbage tag.

Comment: Nuke it from orbit! :)

Comment: Seems pretty worthless, I can't imagine searching for anything specific using that phrase, or imagining anyone who wants to follow a "hardware-combination" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleanup of this tag has been completed.